# Can't remove right margin

Tags: html, css

I have a div inside a fieldset, and I am trying to place a button to the right of it. However, the div has a persistent right margin that I cannot seem to control. If you look in the image below, you will see: 
1. the HTML,
2. how it appears in the browser with the visual overlay provided by chrome dev tools (note the large orange right margin),
3. the css (note I am explicitly setting "margin-right: 2px;")
4. the box model from chrome dev tools (note the right margin is showing as "2", but still it is much wider as shown in #2)

https://i.imgur.com/2rPdNs5.png

How do I get rid of that right margin!?
Thanks.

Comment: Display property must be inline-block and not block

Comment: In the future, please try to avoid screenshots like this. It would have been much better to post the actual code into your answer and possibly create an example on JSFiddle.net to show the behavior in a way that the community can test it.

Comment: Sorry, not "avoid" screenshots, but avoid using them as the only example.

Comment: Adding that the screenshot is not really easy to read..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `display: inline-block;` for `#ageYearFieldset div`.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `float: left` to both `div` and `button` to have the `button` placed on the right of `div`.

Also, you may want to try bootstrap's [input-addon](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) out for accomplishing it.

The margin that is visualized by Chrome dev tools may be confusing, but the thing you should rely on is box model itself.